# Create 2 column index in 1 column document on the same page

Tags: two-column, indexing

I have a document, in which I use the `makeidx` package for creating and index. What I need to do is make the index 2 column, while my document is 1 column and also put it on the same page as my bibliography.

How to make index without a page breaks before and after I found in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23873/149064) but there is nothing about how to make it 2 column in 1 column document.

Also I would like to make sure that all the entries in index will be always split in half between left and right column, so it takes up as little space as possible.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, slovak, twwoside]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=3cm]{geometry}

% Index
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

% Redefine theindex enviroment so it won't place index on new page
% This also makes the index 1 columns, which I don't want
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{theindex}
               {\section*{\indexname}%
                \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
                        {\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
                \thispagestyle{plain}\parindent\z@
                \parskip\z@ \@plus .3\p@\relax
                \columnseprule \z@
                \columnsep 35\p@
                \let\item\@idxitem}
               {}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some one\index{one} column\index{column} block\index{block} of text...

% 2 column index on the same page
\printindex

One column bibliography...
\end{document}
```

So from this example I would like to get a 2 line, 2 column index on the same page as `Some text...` and `One column bibliography...`.

Unewen line spacing:
[image]

Comment: Please share a MWE

Comment: if by uneven line spacing, you mean that there is a greater distance between entries that start with different letters than between entries that start with the same letter, that's by design.  if you want to get rid of it, just `\renewcommand{\indexspace}{}`

Comment: Oh yeah you are right. That's exactly what's happening there :D. It looks kinda bad with so few items but I guess it's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the below suggestion:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, slovak, twwoside]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=3cm]{geometry}

% Index
\usepackage{multicol,makeidx}
\makeindex

% Redefine theindex enviroment so it won't place index on new page
% This also makes the index 1 columns, which I don't want
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{theindex}
               {\section*{\indexname}\begin{multicols}{2}%
                \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
                        {\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
                \thispagestyle{plain}\parindent\z@
                \parskip\z@ \@plus .3\p@\relax
                \columnseprule \z@
                \columnsep 35\p@
                \let\item\@idxitem}
               {\end{multicols}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some one\index{one} column\index{column} block\index{block} of
text...

% 2 column index on the same page
\printindex

One column bibliography...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes this works nicely. The line spacing isn't even for all the items tho.